# Is it possible to install libgl1-mesa-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev on arm64 and arm64 architecture together?

Tags: x86-64, cross-compiling, arm64, ubuntu-22.04, mesa

I am using host on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS to compile the project on amd64 and on arm64. However, I have a problem installing libgl1-mesa-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev libraries. When I have the amd64 version installed and want to install on arm64 this one removes the files from the amd64 version. It works the same way in reverse.

I did some research on the subject, and all I found was that it can't be done and the bug is reported to Ubuntu. However, these questions were posted relatively long ago. I would like to ask if something has changed and someone has found a workaround?